# Replicate selected accounts in ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to replicate selected objects (accounts) in an Active Directory Domain. We have a need to replicate selected accounts through our firewall to a DC sitting in the DMZ. We don't want to replicate *all* accounts to this machine, in case it is compromised.

Any suggestions, help or products suggested most appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apologies - I have just clarified the needs with one of the programmers (slight mis-communication before). Turns out we just need a one-way trust from the DMZ domain, to the internal domain, for accessing some internal objects (files, SQL). I thought they needed to verify some internal users on the DMZ - not so.

Again, apologies, but it turned out to be rather simple.

Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a programming question, but anyway...

Unless the DC on your DMZ is in a different domain, you don't need to replicate anything, it has everything already.  If it's in a different domain, what exactly do you actually want to replicate and why?  Permissions?  Settings?